# Publishing consecutive Pointcloud2 messages for visualization in RViz

Tags: ros-melodic, rviz, pointcloud, point-cloud, pointclouds

I want to view a PointCloud2 topic in RViz. This topic is essentially a 3D map that is being updated incrementally via new PointCloud2 messages. Suppose I have multiple PointCloud2 messages being sent with a 2 second delay between them, will the global PointCloud2 topic visualization in RViz keep all the points from the previous messages? Or will RViz just keep the points from only the latest message? I want to ensure that I keep all the points that have been subscribed to so far in RViz.